# Using a Linq query to select objects where any value of a property matches values from a list

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

So I am trying to filter the modules object list by `userID` of the currently logged in user.  After that I am trying to take the `moduleID` of those selected object.

Using that I want to filter the reports list to only those that contain a `moduleID` that matches any of the the previously obtained list of `moduleID`.

I'm not that particularly knowledgeable on Linq and this is what I came up with:

```
    var name = User.Identity.GetUserName();
        //gets the currently logged in user:
        ApplicationUser currentUser = 
            (ApplicationUser)db.Users.Single(x => x.UserName == name); 
        //gets moduleID's for modules owned by current user:
        var modules = (from i in db.Modules
                       where i.User == currentUser
                       select i.ModuleID); 
        var Reports = from u in db.Reports
                      where u.moduleID == modules
                      select u;
```

I'm having problems with the last portion trying to incorporate the contains method into the statement.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the quick  responses, all good answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simplify the multiple queries to one if I'm inferring your table structure correctly:

```
var name = User.Identity.GetUserName();
var reports = from r in db.Reports
              join m in db.Modules on r.moduleID equals m.ModuleID
              where m.User.UserName == name
              select r;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare a `int` to a `IEnumerable<int>`. However you can check if the `moduleID` is found within the `modules` like this :

```
where modules.Contains(u.moduleID)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track.

```
var Reports = from u in db.Reports
              where modules.Contains(u.moduleID)
              select u;
```

Or using lambda:

```
var reports = db.Reports.Where(u => modules.Contains(u));
```

Answer (score 0):

You're close. In Linq its a little backwards from standard SQL. In its case you want to see if the report's module id is contained in the list of modules, so it would look like this:

```
  var Reports = from u in db.Reports
                where modules.Contains(u.moduleID)
                select u;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the navigation properties if you have a one to many relation you could do directly in your Where clause:

```
var name = User.Identity.GetUserName();
var Reports = db.Reports.Where(x => x.Module.User.Name == name);
```